# Модальное окно popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, modal

Хочу сделать `PopUp` с определенным интервалом, т.е. при открытии страницы появляется `PopUp`, нажал на крестик, через время опять появился `PopUp`.

Например, magnificPopUp только при клике:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.popup-link').magnificPopup();
});
```

Kак сделать его, чтобы PopUp через время сам появлялся?

Comment: `onclick` на нажатие крестика, `setTimeout`, на интервал.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, пока не понял правда куда вставлять,  но постараюсь разобраться =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SetInterval](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#setinterval) - Запускает выполнение функции регулярно повторяет её через указанный интервал времени.

*Задержка в миллисекундах, 1000 миллисекунд равны 1 секунде.*

[**Magnific-popup documentation**](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html)

`$.magnificPopup.open` - Открыть окно напрямую через API

`$.magnificPopup.close` - Закрыть всплывающее окно.

---

```js
$(document).ready(function(){      
  
    setInterval(function() {
      console.log( "тик" );      
      $('.popup-link').magnificPopup();
    }, 1000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
```

**Update "Open magnific"**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){      
    setInterval(function() {
      jQuery.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {src: '.popup-link'},
        type: 'inline'
      });  
      magnificPopupClose();
    }, 2000); 
    
    function magnificPopupClose(){
      setTimeout(function(){
          $.magnificPopup.close(); 
      }, 1000);
    }
});
```

```css
*{
  color: white;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div  class="popup-link">Контент</div>
```

Comment: @VictorKas обновил

Comment: мда, я бы долго это сам писал... спасибо!

Comment: что такое type: 'inline' ?

Comment: @VictorKas  type: 'inline' - Тип контента в окне. Параметр плагина.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){      
    setTimeout(function(){ // открывается через секунды после загрузки страницы можно удалить строку если надо открытие сразу
      $.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {src: '.popup'},
        type: 'inline',
        callbacks: {
          close: function() { // как только первый раз закрыли ставим счетчик
              setTimeout(function(){ // открытие второй раз через 10 секунд после закрытия первого
                $.magnificPopup.open({
                  items: {src: '.popup'},
                  type: 'inline',
                  callbacks: { // колбэк чтобы удалить второе предложение из попапа, чисто для наглядности примера, можно удалить
                    open: function() {
                      $('.popup').text('Кликните по фону для закрытия.'); 
                    },
                  }
                });  
              }, 10000); // 10 секунд
          }
        }
      });  
    }, 1000); // 1 секунда задержки, можно удалить строку если надо открытие сразу
});
```

```css
* {
  color: white;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="popup">Кликните по фону для закрытия. <br/>Через 10 секунд откроется повторно.</div>
```